# "no fix available" error when installing hardhat toolbox

Tags: node.js, npm, solidity, npx, hardhat

after running `npm install --save-dev @nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox`  then `npm audit` the following report appears:

```
# npm audit report

flat  <5.0.1
Severity: critical
flat vulnerable to Prototype Pollution - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-2j2x-2gpw-g8fm
No fix available
node_modules/eth-gas-reporter/node_modules/flat
  yargs-unparser  <=1.6.3
  Depends on vulnerable versions of flat
  node_modules/eth-gas-reporter/node_modules/yargs-unparser
    mocha  5.1.0 - 9.2.1
    Depends on vulnerable versions of minimatch
    Depends on vulnerable versions of yargs-unparser
    node_modules/eth-gas-reporter/node_modules/mocha
      eth-gas-reporter  >=0.2.1
      Depends on vulnerable versions of mocha
      node_modules/eth-gas-reporter
        hardhat-gas-reporter  *
        Depends on vulnerable versions of eth-gas-reporter
        node_modules/hardhat-gas-reporter
          @nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox  *
          Depends on vulnerable versions of hardhat-gas-reporter
          Depends on vulnerable versions of solidity-coverage
          node_modules/@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox

got  <11.8.5
Severity: moderate
Got allows a redirect to a UNIX socket - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-pfrx-2q88-qq97
No fix available
node_modules/got
  web3-bzz  <=1.7.4
  Depends on vulnerable versions of got
  node_modules/web3-bzz
    web3  1.0.0-beta.1 - 1.7.4 || 2.0.0-alpha - 3.0.0-rc.0
    Depends on vulnerable versions of web3-bzz
    node_modules/web3
      @truffle/provider  <=0.3.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of web3
      node_modules/@truffle/provider
        solidity-coverage  0.7.0-beta.0 - 0.8.0-rc.test.0
        Depends on vulnerable versions of @truffle/provider
        node_modules/solidity-coverage

minimatch  <3.0.5
Severity: high
minimatch ReDoS vulnerability - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-f8q6-p94x-37v3
No fix available
node_modules/eth-gas-reporter/node_modules/minimatch

12 vulnerabilities (5 moderate, 4 high, 3 critical)

Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.
```

my nodejs version is **node-v18.14.1-x64**

I'm trying to set up the hardhat development environment by following the tutorial on their website: https://hardhat.org/tutorial

I tried running `npm audit fix --force` but it did not work

Answer (score 0):

Turns out audit is just broken and it was a non-error for all practical purposes.
https://overreacted.io/npm-audit-broken-by-design/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).